# Differences in javascript module pattern

Tags: javascript, module

Very simple question, not sure if there are any differences in these ways of creating a javascript "module". I'm hoping somebody can clarify it for me.

A)

```
var foo = function() {
    var bar = function() {
        console.log('test');
    };

    return {
        bar: bar
    };
};
```

B)

```
var foo = function() {
    function bar() {
        console.log('test');
    };

    return {
        bar: bar
    };
};
```

C)

```
var foo = function() {
    this.bar = function() {
        console.log('test');
    };

    return {    
        bar: this.bar
    };
};
```

Comment: Apart the fact the last wouldn't compile, there is no difference.

Comment: The last one is bad (there's no `self` in JavaScript) but the other two are exactly the same.

Comment: damn it... updating the question :D

Comment: The new last one still doesn't work. It would add a function to any receiver (for example window) if you call it as `foo();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A and B are essentially the same, though there is a very minor difference between A and B due to function/variable hoisting, theoretically you could write code which would work in B but break in A, but practically speaking you'd have to really write weird code to do so.

C will work, but is conceptually wrong. The point of using `this.funcName` in a function is as a constructor (creating lots of objects using `new Thing()`. If you aren't using the function as a constructor you shouldn't be using that style as someone scanning the code may mistake the function as a constructor instead of its actual purpose which is a module.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you forgot to execute the function expression: the [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth) is an IEFE. You just create a function.

Your last example is nonsense, it looks like a constructor function when assigning properties to [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) - and when executed as a IEFE it breaks (and using it with `new` has undesired effects; an when returning an object it's useless).

For the difference between the first and the second snippet see [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname). In context of the module pattern, the function declaration is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Javascript Module Pattern
var person = (function() {
  var cname = 'CheapFlight';
  return {
   name: "Santosh Thakur",
   getAge: function() {
    return cname;
   },
   growOlder: function() {
    return cname + " Updated";
 }
 };
}());
person.cname = "New Company"
console.log(person.cname);
console.log(person.name);
console.log(person.getAge());
console.log(person.growOlder());
```

Answer (score -2):

prefix var before a function makes it a "class"-ish, this means you can make many versions of it. This goes for A

For example:

```
  var hi = function()
  {
    var bye = function()
    {
        alert("bye");
    }   
    bye(); // this will call bye
    var something = new bye(); // this will create a new instance of bye();
  }

  var something = new hi();
  something();
```

B means you can only call bar, not make a new instance of it inside the function.

C is the same as bar because of its scope

Class-ish:

```
var Dog = function( hair, type )
{
     this.hair = hair;
     this.type = type;
}

var fred = new Dog( "long", "Dalmation" );
alert( fred.hair );    

var dave = new Dog( "short", "Poodle" );
alert( dave.type);
```

This is a class ^

Comment: Prefixing `var` does not in the slightest make it a class.

Comment: The `var` is irrelevant, all it will do is change when your function gets declared due to function and variable hoisting. `var Dog = function() {}` is just a different (and imo bad) way of writing `function Dog() {}`

Comment: @mattmanser If you do not declare Dog as a variable... you cannot make new instances of it... It is well documented across the internet. Be careful with that stuff hehe, it can be confusing I know! Try it in your editor, you'll see you cannot make instances of it. It'll only work for one :) I use it for all the games I write, creating arrays of my classes etc :D

Comment: Honestly, it's not: http://jsfiddle.net/Wvt8C/1/  Your way is *definitely* the unconventional way. Go look on MDN or at almost any tutorial. I've seen your style in at most a couple of articles.

Comment: meh, http://jsfiddle.net/72yvh / http://jsfiddle.net/RvrAd/ - lol, one works runtime, one works globally. You can have the last word now. :) Have a wicked day dude! And yes you can make instances of a function using new, which is awesome.. didn't know that! lol... You'd think after 7 years I'd know that ay lollll